# How To Produce Multidimensional Array From While Loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this function :

```
function userKids(mysqli $Con, $Parent) {
    $stmt = $Con->prepare('SELECT KidsName, KidsAge, KidsGender FROM Kids WHERE Parent = ?');
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $Username);
    $stmt->execute();

    $Kid = null;
    $Kids = array();
    $stmt->bind_result($Kid, $KidsAge, $KidsGender);
    while($stmt->fetch()) {
        $Kids[] = $Kid;
    }
    return $Kids;
}
```

currently my WHILE loop produce array like this :

```
Array ( [0] => john [1] => jane )
```

Now, how to produce multidimensional array so I can get the Age and Gender as well, like this :

```
Array
(
[john] => Array
  (
  [0] => 3
  [1] => male
  )
[jane] => Array
  (
  [0] => 2
  [1] => female
  )
)
```

Comment: you can benefit a lot from Object Oriented Programming, Robert

Comment: What you want will overwrite results, if you have 2 **kids** with name "John". I hope you notice.

Comment: Try to put not `KidsName` as array key, but something unique, like `IDKid`, so it never might be repeated in `SELECT` result set. Or just leave your idea. Your choise.

Comment: @CORRUPT : you're such a brilliant man, bro!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you use an associative array for the second dimension as well. So:

```
$Kids[$Kid] = array('age' => $KidsAge, 'gender' => $KidsGender);
```

Answer (score 4):

Change the line:

```
$Kids[] = $Kid;
```

To:

```
$Kids[$Kid] = array($KidsAge, $KidsGender);
```

Comment: As CORRUPT has mentioned, your solution will overwrite duplicate first names.

Answer (score 1):

replace the end of your code by:

```
$stmt->bind_result($KidName, $KidAge, $KidGender);
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $Kids[$KidName] = array($KidAge,$KidGender);
}
return $Kids;
```